# Fast Integer Square Roots of known perfect squares?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

A bit of a generic question perhaps - say I have a list of non-negative integers and I know each are perfect squares  - what is a fast way of finding their square roots? I have very long lists (millions of elements) and the numbers range from say 0 to 100,000 or so? The inbuilt Sqrt[] function is not particularly fast.

Comment: This might be relevant https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165041/9469

Comment: Thanks. I actually saw that but though faster it still seemed quite slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a lookup table:

```
m = 1000;
n = 1000000;
ClearAll[f];
f = AssociationThread[Range[0, m]^2, Range[0, m]];
a = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, n]^2;

b = Lookup[f, a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[a - b^2]]
```

> 0.115421
>
> 0

Using a sparse vector seem to be a bit more efficient:

```
sv = SparseArray[Partition[Range[0, m]^2 + 1, 1] -> Range[0, m]];
b = sv[[a + 1]]; // RepeatedTiming
Max[Abs[a - b^2]]
```

> 0.0387735
>
> 0

If the maximum square is not too large, a plain array can also serve as lookup table (but is basically a waste of space):

```
v = Normal[sv];
b = v[[a + 1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[a - b^2]]
```

> 0.00675104
>
> 0

Or (apparently much faster) convert to doubles and round afterwards:

```
b = Round[Sqrt[N[a]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[a - b^2]]
```

> 0.00246308
>
> 0

The last variant is probably the best as it is the least memory bound one. It leverages that square roots of doubles are implemented in hardware nowadays.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about a lookup table but was too lazy on a Sunday morning to code it up. I know - that's beyond lazy.

Comment: Thanks for that last one especially  - something like that was crossing my mind but on thinking about it I didn't pursue it. I doubt that can be much improved upon. The reason this came up is I was trying to do PowersRepresentations faster using IntegerPartitions - which is far faster but the output gives me the squares of the numbers and I need their square roots.

Comment: You're welcome!